# Multiple object on HTML5 CANVAS, only first item is drawn

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

Please consider such code, `draw()` function is called in each animation loop, where stage is cleared and gradient is applied to a background and x,y are changed for shapes:

```
draw = function() {
    for ( i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++ )
    {
        draw_sample_shape(i);
        draw_coords(i);
    }
}

draw_sample_shape = function(shape) {
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(shapes[shape].x, shapes[shape].y, 240, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}

draw_coords(shape) {
    coords = shapes[shape].coords;
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(coords[0].x, coords[0].y);
    for ( i = 1; i < coords.length; i++ )
    {
        if (coords[i].y == 'X' && coords[i].x == 'X')
        {
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
            ctx.beginPath();
            if (typeof(coords[i+1]) != 'undefined')
            {
                ctx.moveTo( (coords[i+1].x), (coords[i+1].y) );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ctx.lineTo((coords[i].x), (coords[i].y));
        }
    }
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}
```

Now everything works perfect, unless I call `draw_coords()` in my `draw()` function - the problem is it draws and animates only the first shape, and skips the rest of them. When I skip this call it works OK.

I use the [X,X] coords to reset drawing, and start the next shape.
Can someone tell me what is wrong with that? and why when I draw that coords it only draws them on first element?

Comment: Can you give us an example for "shapes"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know why you're getting a problem. It's this line:

`for ( i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++ )`

You are saying `i = 0` instead of `var i = 0`.

This means that `i` is global.

This means that the `i` in `draw_coords` is actually clobbering your `i` in `draw()`!

So you start on the first object in `draw()` with `i` being `0`, then you go into draw_coords and it takes the same `i` variable and increments it to something large, like `10`. Then when the first draw_coords is done it goes back to draw and sees if `i`, which is now `10`, is less than shapes.length (which might be something like 6). It's not less, so the for loop in `draw` considers itself done!

You definitely don't want this, so change both of your for loops to have var:

`for (var i = 0;`

And the problem you're having here about will go away.

Comment: Thanks man! That was it... I was struggling with that problem for almost whole day.